# Seaborn lmplot truncates trendline for some plots

Tags: python, seaborn

When I run the following code, the regression line for some of the plots is truncated, even though I specified truncate=False.

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
sns.lmplot(x='total_bill',y='tip',data=tips,truncate=False,col='day',hue='sex')
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA0Ca.png

Is there any way to make it so the line extends to the limits in all of the plots?

Comment: Might be an issue with the backend you're using. Your code results in [this](https://imgur.com/a/sd7RKiT) for me (Python 3.8.2, seaborn 0.10.0, running on an IPython shell).

Comment: This is a matplotlib issue: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/15967

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK This is ultimately a matplotlib issue (see comment), but it can be worked around:

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=tips, col="day", hue="sex")
g.set(xlim=(0, 55))
g.map(sns.regplot, "total_bill", "tip", truncate=False)
g.add_legend()
```

[image]